# How to block VPN connections from accessing website? (linux, ubuntu)

Tags: block, firewall, vpn

usually, the people who access our website and use VPNs are up to no good. How do websites like skrill, Netflix, advertisement portals block VPNs? Do they block the ports used by VPNs in ubuntu firewall?

Would be grateful for an answer.

Answer (score 2):

There's no reliable way of knowing that you're serving traffic to a user behind a VPN.

Websites that do block VPNs will probably be using a combination of techniques, but they have drawbacks...

- Use a blacklist of known VPN IP addresses. This works to some extent and there are databases and APIs you can use, but they can't technically cover every VPN on the internet and doesn't make sense to block VPNs running in dynamic IP pools.
- Port scanning. A website can essentially port scan an IP address to check if it has VPN server ports open. But it can easily be worked around by changing to non-standard ports, and you also risk blocking legitimate users that have a VPN server running on their home computer.